# Próximo elemento de um array apos execução

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se é possível um script em php retornar o próximo elemento de uma array toda vez que é executado.
Exemplo:

```
$numeros = array(1, 2, 3);
```

Quando o script é carregado retorna 1, na próxima execução retorna 2, assim por diante, sem usar cookies, sql e arquivo de texto.

Comment: Algum controle será necessário!

Comment: Imaginei isso, só queria ter certeza que não existe essa função no php.